# Wildfly 10 failing to load MySQL XA driver on startup

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jboss, xa

I have a web application I am deploying in wildfly-10.0.0. It requires a mysql xa driver. I have the following error:

> 2015-10-13 12:25:37,979 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("jdbc-driver" => "com.mysql")
>   ]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"

The modules directory is as follows:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\rball\Documents\Dev\WildFly\wildfly-10.0.0.CR1\modules\sy
stem\layers\base\com\mysql\main

10/13/2015  11:32 AM    <DIR>          .
10/13/2015  11:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/13/2015  12:25 PM             1,575 module.xml
03/17/2015  05:21 AM           968,670 mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
```

The module.xml file is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>      
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

I added the driver and datasource to the datasources section of standalone.xml:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/MyXaDS" pool-name="MyXaDSPool" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                    <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>1000</background-validation-millis>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Comment: Any ideas out there on fixing this. I have looked at everything I can find on the web with no resolution

Answer (score 8):

The error you get means that wildfly expects a module called `com.mysql` but it doesn't exist or it isn't registered under that name.

You are missing one step, which is registering the datasource jdbc driver. The first step of course being adding the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar` file and `module.xml` file in `WILDFLY_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main`.

To get rid of your error, stop wildfly, delete the the driver declaration in your standalone.xml by removing these lines; We'll let the /subsystem command create this entry.

```
<driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
     <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
     <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Open your command prompt and navigate to `WILDFLY_HOME\bin\` and run the following commands.

1. Connect to jboss cli by running : `jboss-cli.bat --connect` . In case your management console is running on a different port say , localhost:9991, use `jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9991`
2. Then register the jdbc-driver with the following command

   `/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=com.mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)`

You should get the response `{"outcome" => "success"}` if this was successful.
From there, reload your server and you should get rid of that error.

I got pointers from [This link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html)

Comment: This link also helped, though you may need a subscription account:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/660933

Comment: If the server doesn't start, how can I connect to the jboss-cli?

Comment: For Postgres, use
`/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=com.postgresql:add(driver-name=com.postgresql,driver-module-name=com.postgresql,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what the issue could be. The message isn't very informative.

That said the following `add-mysql.cli` script worked for me.

```
module add --name=com.mysql --resources=~/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

batch
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=com.mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql, driver-module-name=com.mysql, driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql, jndi-name="java:/jdbc/MySQLXA", enabled=true)
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=mysql/xa-datasource-properties=URL:add(value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8")
run-batch
```

I didn't write all the properties defined in your data source configuration, but this did work.

Answer (score 1):

WildFly 10 has some change in jca caused CLI create xa ds have some issue.
    https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6773
    https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6789
    https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6774

But create xa datasouces use below commands works

```
xa-data-source add --name=MariaDBXADS --driver-name=mariadb-xa --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/MariaDBXADS --user-name=jdv_user --password=jdv_pass --use-java-context=true --xa-datasource-properties=[DatabaseName=>products, PortNumber=>3306, ServerName=>localhost]
```

Answer (score 1):

WILDFLY 10 using MySQL 5.7

Follow these steps: comment or delete `exampleds` in standalone.xml

```
into jboss-cli.bat --connect
```

After execute command:

> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)

should be ok.

This modified standalone.xml, then add:

```
<datasources>
  <!-- 
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-

    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
      <driver>h2</driver>
      <security>
          <user-name>sa</user-name>
          <password>sa</password>
      </security>
    </datasource> 
  -->
  <datasource jndi-name="java:/mysql" pool-name="mysqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wildfly</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>jdfoxito10</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
  <drivers>
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
      <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
  </drivers>
</datasources>
```

should look like!

and module.xml put in

> \java\server\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main

`mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` (come installer mysql-installer-community-5.7.15.0.msi) module.xml

and content from module.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

and ready, `JAVA_HOME` should be ok